# Multiple View Controllers for a TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with 5 Tabs.
One of the Tabs "Info" has a ViewController (as always).

The View in this ViewContoller has 3 buttons - Info1, Info2 and Info3.
The TabController is set to load "Info1" as default.
When clicking these buttons, each should open a new ViewController and it´s View.
It should not be "modal" but should belong to the TabBar Controller (so the TabBar is visible and working).
I do not wan´t a navigation Controller since the buttons could be pressed in any order.

Is it possible to:
- Change/replace a ViewController for the "Info"-tab?

I noticed in Apple dokumentation that ALL Viewcontrollers for a TabBarController could be set/changed. But isn´t there a way to change only one of them?

Anyway: I REALLY appreciate the stackoverflow site! I have found a ton of tips that helped me developing apps. There is only good answers and good manners all over. This is my first question here. Thanks!

Comment: Could you just add a subview above your view?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to make this in interface builder, then you could just drag the view-controllers into the tab bar, then it becomes buttons. It's really easy!

If you would like to make it programaticaly as the app starts up, you could make UITabBarItems, and implement the UITabBarDelegate and watch for "tabBar:didSelectItem:"

But, as i said. Interface builder is the simplest!

Comment: I do want them under the SAME TabBarItem, i.e "Info-tab".
The ViewController for this Tab has 3 buttons. Each of the buttons should switch the ViewController for "Info-Tab".

Comment: You'll need to explain further. I can't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the original question and hopes this is a better description.

Comment: Found the answer in another forum:
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = WhatEverController;